# Making sub menu run horizontal

Tags: html, css, html-lists, submenu

I'm having a bit of trouble turning my vertical sub menu into a horizontal one, everything I try seems to be incorrect or I end up changing the rest of the look of the main menu.

HTML

```
    <nav>
            <ul>

                <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>

                <li><a href="justjoelabout.html">ABOUT</a></li>

                <li><a href='#'><span>WORK</span></a>

            <ul>

                    <li class="services1">

                    <a href="justjoelprint.html">PRINT</a>

                    <a href="justjoelbranding.html">BRANDING</a>

                    <a href="justjoeleditorial.html">EDITORIAL</a>

                    <a href="justjoelphotography.html">PHOTOGRAPHY</a>

                    </ul>

                    </li>

                <li><a href="justjoelblog.html">BLOG</a></li>

                <li><a href="justjoelinspired.html">INSPIRED</a></li>

                <li><a href="justjoelcontact.html">CONTACT</a></li>

            </ul>

    </nav>
```

Here is the CSS

```
 nav {
height: 70px;
float: left;
font-size: 20px;
color: #00BCDC;
font-family: "geogtq md";
 }

 nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
color: #00BBE4;
font-family: "geogtq md";
float: left;
display:inline; 
 }

 nav li {
float: left;
margin-right: 20px;
color: #00BBE4;
font-family: "geogtq md";
margin-left: auto;
display: inline;
 }

 a:link {
text-decoration: none;
color: #00C0EE;
font-family: "geogtq md";
 }
 a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color: #00C0EE;
 }
 a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: #007889;
 }
 a:active {
text-decoration: none;
color: #00C0EE;
 }


 ul {
font-family: "geogtq md";
font-size: 20px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
 }
 ul li {
display: inline;
position: relative;
float: left;
 }

 li ul {
display: none;
 }

 ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
margin-right:5px;
white-space: nowrap;
color:#066;
 }

 li:hover ul {
display: inline;
position: absolute;
 }

 li:hover li {
float: none;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight:bold;
margin-top:3px;
 }

 .services1 a {
color:#00C0EE;
float: left;
list-style-type: none;
display:inline;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GMbCU/

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this has been going on for a while and would help with how things sit on my site, thanks

Comment: Each of your sub-items should probably be its own LI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give the child UL enough width and place each link in its own LI. You already have them displaying inline.

http://jsfiddle.net/GMbCU/7

```
li ul {
    width: 450px;
}
```

Comment: Thank, that's a big help. The only thing is how would i extend the margin of the sub items without extending the margin of the main menu items?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but you can easily target the child items with CSS. Anything beginning with the selector above will do so.

Comment: That's the issue. If i change any of the 'li ul' elements it affects the line saying 'home' 'about' when i only want to change the look of the sub menu below it

Comment: That's impossible. Show your selector.

Comment: All my selectors, of the whole CSS?

Comment: No, just the one you claim breaks parent elements.

Comment: li ul {
    display: none;
    width: 450px;
 margin-right: 20px;
}
ul li a {
    font-family:"geogtq md";
 text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color:#066;
 margin-right: 20px;

Comment: Your second selector should be something like: ul ul li a {}.

Answer (score 0):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/pzC2g/

```
<nav>
    <ul class='root'>
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="justjoelabout.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>WORK</span></a>
            <ul class='sub'>
                <li><a href="justjoelprint.html">PRINT</a></li>
                <li><a href="justjoelbranding.html">BRANDING</a></li>
                <li><a href="justjoeleditorial.html">EDITORIAL</a></li>
                <li><a href="justjoelphotography.html">PHOTOGRAPHY</a></li>    
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="justjoelblog.html">BLOG</a></li>
        <li><a href="justjoelinspired.html">INSPIRED</a></li>
        <li><a href="justjoelcontact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and css

```
.root {
    display: block;
}

.root li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.root li .sub {
    display: none;
}

.root li:hover .sub {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

.root li:hover .sub li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated the above with Styles, see link : http://jsfiddle.net/pzC2g/27/
Thanks Goldj for great support,

**

```css
*, html{
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}

nav{
 background-color: #222;
 
}

.wrapper{
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0px;
max-width: 1150px;
min-height:100%;
}


.root {
    display: block;
}

.root li {
    padding:10px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
 color: #fff;
}

.root li:hover{
  background-color:#555;
}

.root li a{ 
   display:block;
   text-decoration:none;
   color:inherit;
  
}
.root li a:hover{
  display:block;
 
}

.root li .sub {
    background-color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #222;
 margin-top: 10px;
 left:0;
 width:99.9%;
 display: none;
 font-size:14px;
}

.root li:hover .sub {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

.root li:hover .sub li {
 color: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.root li .sub li:hover {
    background-color: #222;  
 color: #fff;
 }
```

```html
<nav>
   <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class='root'>
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>WORK</span></a>
            <ul class='sub'>
       <div class="wrapper">
                <li><a href="justjoelprint.html">PRINT</a></li>
                <li><a href="justjoelbranding.html">BRANDING</a></li>
                <li><a href="justjoeleditorial.html">EDITORIAL</a></li>
                <li><a href="justjoelphotography.html">PHOTOGRAPHY</a></li> 
                </div>    
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">INSPIRED</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**